# Hubot - Botframework - MS Teams - Not responding

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, hubot

I have created a localhost-based `Hubot` and used Botframework as adapter. I created a MS bot account. I also created a new app using app studio in MS Teams. I then side loaded it. I started `ngrok` and I started everything up. I can see the bot is online in Teams. But when I sent a command to bot, it accepts the message but does not respond. In the log it looks like it's responding but I don't see the response in the Teams channel or @mention. Please see the log below

```
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:51 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: creating middleware...
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:51 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: TextMiddleware toReceivable
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: onBotEvents
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: Handling activity Channel: msteams; type: message
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: creating middleware...
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-msteams: toReceivable
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: send
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: reply
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: creating middleware...
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:39:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-msteams: toSendable
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: onBotEvents
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: Handling activity Channel: msteams; type: message
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: creating middleware...
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-msteams: toReceivable
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: send
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: reply
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: creating middleware...
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-msteams: toSendable
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: send
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: reply
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: creating middleware...
[Mon Jun 24 2019 17:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-msteams: toSendable
```

App manifest:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "packageName": "com.tech.bot",
    "developer": {
        "name": "user",
        "websiteUrl": "https://mm.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://mm.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://mm.com/terms"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "techbot",
        "full": ""
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "bot for techbot",
        "full": "bot for techbot"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "xxxxxxxxd",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "commandLists": [
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "personal"
                    ],
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "title": "hi",
                            "description": "How are u!!!"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "team"
                    ],
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "title": "hi",
                            "description": "Greet!!!"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "hi",
                            "description": "How are u!!!"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "groupchat"
                    ],
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "title": "hi",
                            "description": "Greet!!!"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "hi",
                            "description": "How are u!!!"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": []
}
```

The debug log shows below

```
  express:router dispatching POST /api/messages +44s
  express:router query  : /api/messages +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /api/messages +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/messages +1ms
  express:router query  : /api/messages +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /api/messages +0ms
  body-parser:json content-type "application/json; charset=utf-8" +0ms
  body-parser:json content-encoding "identity" +1ms
  body-parser:json read body +0ms
  body-parser:json parse body +0ms
  body-parser:json parse json +0ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /api/messages +0ms
  body-parser:urlencoded body already parsed +0ms
  express:router multipart  : /api/messages +0ms
[Wed Jun 26 2019 08:33:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: onBotEvents
[Wed Jun 26 2019 08:33:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-adapter: Handling activity Channel:                            msteams; type: message
[Wed Jun 26 2019 08:33:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-botframework-middleware: creating middleware...
  finalhandler cannot 404 after headers sent +6ms
```

Comment: Could you please share your app manifest?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT : Added manifest

Comment: Does the bot respond in the Bot Framework Emulator?

Comment: @KyleDelaney If I configure Ngrok directly in Botframework eulator. Yeah sure it works.

Comment: Do you have a Bot Channels Registration resource in Azure?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: No I don't. I dont even use Azure. I created bot using this link https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new and not the link in Azure.

Comment: @Damien-Amen- Could you please share the bot id so that we could check the backend service logs for your issues? Also, Just wanted to confirm that you have [added Microsoft Teams as channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt4sc.png) for your Bot?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT: Bot ID db972f0d-d2e8-4e6d-b63f-27eec53fea4d . I have also added additional log messages in my OP

Comment: Are you getting any response when you [Test In WebChat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZz4I.png)? Do you see any issues in your [channels page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA1sx.png)? Could you please confirm if you are able to run any other simple bots like [Hello World](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#download-the-sample)?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: Yes, I'll report on Monday for sure.

Comment: @Damien-Amen- Did you get chance to test it?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT - Yes, Test in webchat did not work. It says "message not sent" (or something similar). I don't see any issues in the channels page. It just says "Running". I tried it with different laptops and also different networks.

Comment: Can you try running an echo bot to see if you can connect to that?